Crystal Reports, Enter unique parameters into array, not using multiple values for a parameter
In Crystal reports, created a parameter to get multiple values to function as an array.  I found I cannot enter same value twice. User needs to enter quantity for each box received.  If box1=5, box2=3, box3=7, then no problem.  If box1=3, box2=5, and box3=3... I cannot enter the value for Box. Thus, I created 3 parameters (actually I want 12) and I want to load them into an array as follows:
//create an array of box quantities
NumberVar Array BoxQtys
    Redim BoxQtys[Ubound({?Box Count})];

    //populate array
    Numbervar i;
    for i := 1 to Ubound(BoxQtys) do (
         BoxQtys[i] := {?Box 1 Qty}
    );

My problem is how to set the parameter as a series of parsed strings where BoxQtys[i] = "{Box " & i & Qty}".  Is there a way to do what I want or do I have to go the long route of defining each element in the array without a loop?
Thanks
Tony
Please see above. I was going to use SPLIT() with ; delimiter, but users would then have to enter a string of numbers with semi-colons.  There are a lot of ways that could go wrong.  Having 12 number fields ensures correct entry.

Given that the number of boxes might vary, you may want to avoid designing the report with the maximum number of parameters (because that would require the user to ignore the surplus parameters.
A possible solution is to use a UFL, so a single formula would result in a popup prompt with the exact number of input fields.

Thanks, but I am not familiar with UFL.  Can you elaborate a bit?  I like the idea of not popping up 12 parameters when only 3 are needed.

UFL: Crystal Reports User Function Library.
If you are not familiar with writing a UFL yourself (C# or VB), you can get a UFL developed by a 3rd-party. Ken Hamady maintains a listing of 3rd-party UFLs here: https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl

One of the UFLs listed by Ken already has a dynamic InputBox() function.

Thanks for the UFL links.  I found a workaround.
